# Singleton object in java play! framework

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, singleton

I'm really new to the Play! framework and I'm having troubles. Basically I'm making a web app whose first action is to read a Model from a file, I only need to do this once and never again, but this model has to be available for  the controllers in the web app. I usually accomplish this behaviour in java creating a singleton which can be called by other classes. However, I don't know how can I do this with Play!.

I've read about the [Global object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGlobal) but it seems it's only used for managing global settings, not for handling singletons. I will appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a... singleton class as usually (simplified sample)

```
package utils;

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton ourInstance = new MySingleton();
    private String myModel = null;

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private MySingleton() {
        play.Logger.debug("READING FILE AND SETTING myModel field... almost ;)");
        myModel = "Value from somewhere";
    }

    public String getMyModel() {
        return myModel;
    }
}
```

so in your Global class you can initialize it first within `onStart` method:

```
public void onStart(Application app) {
    MySingleton.getInstance();
    super.onStart(app);
}
```

you will also have access to it from other class in the same way:

```
String mySingletonsModel = MySingleton.getInstance().getMyModel();
```